# Show custom dialog setRouteLeaveHook or history.listenBefore react-router/redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux

I cant seem to figure out how to show a custom dialogue instead of using the normal `window.confirm` that `routeWillLeave` and `history.listenBefore` uses. Basically i have built a notification system and check if a form is dirty `const { dispatch, history, dirty } = this.props;`

if the form is dirty it means the user has unsaved changes. If they change route I would like to show my notification which will have two buttons `STAY`, `IGNORE` which can both take an onClick handler.

Ive spent a bit of time googling and havent come across any mention of how i might accomplish this using `routeWillLeave`. The closest thing i could find was to use `history.listenBefore` however there docs say that I need to do this.

```
let history = createHistory({
  getUserConfirmation(message, callback) {
    callback(window.confirm(message)) // The default behavior
  }
})
```

But I am using browserHistory from react-router to initiate my store `const history = syncHistoryWithStore(browserHistory, store);`

How can I stop a route change after a link has been clicked, show a notification using my custom notification system and depending on which button is clicked either transition to the new route or stay?

Here is an example of how my notification system works and the direction ive headed in which obviously doesn't work because all this returns is a string to show in the window.confirm dialogue by default.

```
history.listenBefore((location) => {
  if(this.props.dirty){
    const acceptBtn = {
      title: 'STAY',
      handler: ignoreRouteChange() //This can be any function I want
    }
    const denyBtn = {
      title: 'IGNORE',
      handler: continueRouteChange() //This can be any function I want
    }
    return dispatch(addNotification({
      message: 'You have unsaved changes!',
      type: NOTIFICATION_TYPE_WARNING,
      duration: 0,
      canDismiss: false,
      acceptBtn,
      denyBtn
    }));
    return "Usaved changes!"
  }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I just answered a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35793421/52041

Comment: Thanks for that, just out of curiosity how did you come up with that solution? Did you delve into how setRouterLeaveHook was implemented and re-implemented it to provide an asynv version or..?

Comment: No, I just did a bit of brainstorming with a colleague, based on the behavior of setRouterLeaveHook.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that i have decided to use is to return false in the normal setRouterLeaveHook callback and then show my dialog and use the nextLocation passed to the callback to push the next route depending on button selection.

```
router.setRouteLeaveHook(route, this.routerWillLeave.bind(this));

routerWillLeave(nextLocation){
  let { dirty, dispatch, resetForm } = this.props;
  if (dirty) {
    let dialog = {
      id: Date.now(),
      showTitle: true,
      titleContent: 'Unsaved Changes',
      titleIcon: 'fa fa-warning',
      content: <span>You have <strong>unsaved</strong> changes! <strong>Discard</strong> them?</span>,
      type: 'confirm',
      handleCloseClick: (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(closeDialog());
      },
      acceptBtn: {
        title: 'Okay',
        handler: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          resetForm();
          // Wait for call stack to unwind and then execute
          // the following which will now have the updated values.
          setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(push(nextLocation));
            dispatch(closeDialog());
          }, 0);
        }
      },
      denyBtn: {
        title: 'Deny',
        handler: (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          dispatch(closeDialog());
        }
      }
    }
    dispatch(addDialogWindow(dialog));
    dispatch(openDialog(false, (e) => dispatch(closeDialog()), false));
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why props are not updated yet without using `setTimeout` ?

Comment: In the case where a user is trying to navigate away by using the browser's back button wouldn't this behave weirdly -> Your code would be pushing a new location onto the history instead of going back in the history?